# How to fit a linear regression model using three independent variables and calculate the mean squared error using sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression, mse

I'm trying to fit a linear regression model using three independent variables and calculate the mean squared error using sklearn, but I seem not be able to get it right.

My data is the Boston Housing, and three independent variables are as follow: 
1. CRIM (per capita crime rate by town)
2. RM (average number of rooms per dwelling)
3. PTRATIO (pupil-teacher ratio by town)

Fit model:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X[['CRIM']['RM'], ['PTRATIO']], boston_df.PRICE)
```

Calculate the mean square error

```py
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
y_true = ['CRIM', 'RM', 'PTRATIO']
y_pred = ['PRICE']
mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
```

Any advice or hints are much appreciated!

Comment: What happens? You forgot to mention what the problem is

Comment: I fail in fitting the linear regression model and calculating the mean square error. Thanks for your reply!!

Comment: I mean, please post the actual error message

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry...
Fit model:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
and Calculate the MSE: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `X[['CRIM', 'RM', 'PRTATIO']]` instead of `X[['CRIM']['RM'], ['PTRATIO']]` for fitting the model

For prediction you need to compare these two vectors:

```
y_true = boston_df.PRICE
y_pred = lm.predict(X[['CRIM', 'RM', 'PRTATIO']])
mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
```

Basically your `y_pred` should be the predicted values from your model which is `lm` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

sklearn has great documentation.  Here is a super thorough example complete with example data set: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html

The biggest problem that you are having is your data set.  Like your code here:

```
y_true = ['CRIM', 'RM', 'PTRATIO']
y_pred = ['PRICE']
```

That isn't even real data, it is just 2 lists of string labels, so of course this won't work:

```
mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
```

From the example I posted, you could try this "hello world" type code (using existing data sets) just to make sure you are getting the code working, then all you need to do is replace the dataset with your own data.  As you can see most of the code is dedicated to preparing the data so it will load correctly into the linear regression function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model

# Load the diabetes dataset
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()

# Use only one feature
diabetes_X = diabetes.data[:, np.newaxis, 2]

# Split the data into training/testing sets
diabetes_X_train = diabetes_X[:-20]
diabetes_X_test = diabetes_X[-20:]

# Split the targets into training/testing sets
diabetes_y_train = diabetes.target[:-20]
diabetes_y_test = diabetes.target[-20:]

# Create linear regression object
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# Train the model using the training sets
regr.fit(diabetes_X_train, diabetes_y_train)

print("Mean squared error: %.2f" % np.mean((regr.predict(diabetes_X_test) - diabetes_y_test) ** 2))
```

Comment: In this case you split the dataset, but would it make sense to do something like                                                                                                             `regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()`  then `regr.fit(diabetes_X, diabetes.target)` and then finally `np.mean((regr.predict(diabetes_X, diabetes.target)**2)` ? Would this make sense? Because I would like to see how good the fit is in terms of the error. So I thought I could use the same whole dataset... Is this a good approach?

Comment: @Euler_Salter generally speaking if you use the same data to train a model and then test a model then you're not really predicting anything since the model already "knows" the right answer for each input, so doing like that doesn't really make sense.  Although you are free to try, of course give it a shot.  Since this is a linear regression, depending on your data it still probably won't be able to make perfect predictions.  Also double check the mean squared error line from my example, you seem to have miswrote it.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind true I miswrote it indeed! Okay thank you! So basically the best choices are either the train/test split or cross validation? And in this case, is cross validation (or test/train split) going to be slow for big datasets?